Finding out the last users who modified a file in a folder
I'm currently working on an assignment where I need to return a list of users who last modified files within a specific folder. I have imported the folder into a dataframe using the Python library Folderstats. These folders contain different types of files (e.g., doc, docx, jpg, png, etc.).
Is there a way to retrieve the user who last modified each file in the folder? Any advice or pointers on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Most systems will return information on a file via a call to stat (or one of its variants). So check the documentation for the operating system that you are working on. The Python documentation can be found in  the section at os — Miscellaneous operating system interfaces However, unless the information includes details of the user then there is no easy way to get the answer.

The user of an access is typically not recorded, expect you have a special system setup to do so.
